# In Ruby, when initializing a new class that only contains nil, why is nil still being returned after I shovel a string into it?

Tags: ruby

I have the following library:

```
class RollCall < Array                                                               

  def initialize(name = nil)                                                         
    @name = name                                                                     
  end                                                                                

  def longest_name                                                                   
    @name                                                                            
  end                                                                                
end
```

Along with the following test cases:

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'                                                             
require 'minitest/autorun'                                                           
require 'minitest/pride'                                                             
require_relative '../lib/roll_call'                                                  

class RollCallTest < Minitest::Test                                                  
  def test_no_names                                                                  
    roll_call = RollCall.new                                                         
    assert_equal nil, roll_call.longest_name                                         
  end                                                                                

  def test_longest_of_one                                                            
    roll_call = RollCall.new                                                         
    roll_call << 'Oda'                                                               
    assert_equal 'Oda', roll_call.longest_name                                       
  end                                                                                                                                                              
end
```

Why does `roll_call.longest_name` return `nil`? In IRB, it returns `['Oda']` (I realize that still doesn't pass the test, this is just where I'm getting stuck en route).

Comment: Don't subclass Ruby's core-classes. They are heavily optimized and – even when done right – full of surprises. Instead, define an array inside your class and delegate the needed methods like `<<` to it.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the tip. I tried that before, however, I'm still grappling with `nil` being returned instead of the desired string (or aforementioned array containing a string), `TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer`. This is when I try to define a new array inside of the class inside of the `longest_name` method, `Array.new(@name)`.

Comment: _"In IRB, it returns ['Oda']"_ – I assume that `roll_call` returns `['Oda']`, calling `roll_call.longest_name` should also give `nil` in IRB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `roll_call.longest_name` return `nil`?

Your `longest_name` method merely returns the `@name` instance variable. It gets set in `initialize` but not when calling `roll_call << 'Oda'`. That's because the `<<` method is defined in `Array`, and `Array` isn't aware of your subclass or the `@name` instance variable.

You shouldn't subclass Ruby's core classes in the first place. Instead, wrap an array instance inside your class. Something like this should work:

```
class RollCall
  def initialize
    @names = []
  end

  def <<(name)
    @names << name
    self             # <- this allows you to chain multiple << calls
  end

  def longest_name
    @names.max_by(&:length)
  end
end

r = RollCall.new
r.longest_name #=> nil

r << 'Bob'
r.longest_name #=> "Bob"
```

Comment: I see, now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @en1on you're welcome :-) Also note that `RollCall` no longer inherits from `Array`

Comment: Note that your code leaks private internal state, since `Array#<<` returns its receiver, and `@names << name` is the last expression evaluated inside `RollCall#<<`, thus returning the internal `@names` array. Matching the semantics of `Array#<<` and all the other existing implementations of `<<`, it would be better to explicitly return `self` at the end. (If I do `a = r << 'blabla'`, I now have a reference to the supposedly private internal array.)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `roll_call.longest_name` return `nil`?

`RollCall#longest_name` simply returns the value of `@name`. There is exactly one place in your code where `@name` is modified, and that is `RollCall#initialize`. Therefore, the *only way* that `longest_name` can ever return anything other than `nil` is by passing an argument to `RollCall#initialize`, or rather `RollCall::new`.

Since you are not doing that, the only result you will ever get is `nil`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.